# How to differentiate which UIImagePickerController calling the func didCancel if I have two image views on same view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have two `UIImageView`s (`leftImageView` & `rightImageView`) on same view. I'm trying to know which `UIImagePickerController` is calling the `imagePickerControllerDidCancel`. Is it the `leftImageView` or the right one?

Here's the switch for the picker buttons to pick the left or right image.

```
switch sender.tag {
    // left image
case 0:
    self.imageView = leftImage
default:
    self.imageView = rightImage
}
```

The func below is able to know which image view is calling it. But the didCancel func does not:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) { 
    // the rightImageView or the leftImageView calling the cancel?

    if (rightImageView){
        // print("the right image ")
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: it's not a right practice to declare an imageView that points to 1 of 2 declared

Comment: Could you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the info you need. Check `self.imageView`:

```
if self.imageView === leftImageView {
    // it's the left image view
} else {
    // it's the right image view
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you present it assign a `tag`

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController() // make it an instance var


picker.view.tag = 20
self.present(......
```

and check it in cancel

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
  if picker.view.tag == 20 {
    // left
  }
  else {
   // right
  }
}
```